# style is not working for kendo calendar

Tags: calendar, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Hi I'm trying to change the font color of my calendar footer like below. But it is not working. Can someone figure out what is the issue here? Except color remaining style are working like background, font etc.

```
  #calendar.k-footer {
                    color: #ff0000;
                    font-family: cursive;
                }
```

same thing is not working for selected date also

```
#calendar .k-state-selected{
                    color: #ff0000;
                    background: transparent;
                }
```

Anything wrong in the above style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a space between #calendar and .k-footer:

```
#calendar .k-footer a {
}
```

Here is a live demo:http://jsbin.com/akibeh/3/edit

Comment: Hey I've given space already.. but in your demo also color is not getting changed only font is changed.

Comment: And one more thing is there anyway to apply background color for footer? I've applied but it is applying for only text (Tuesday, June 25, 2013). But I wanted to apply background color for entire footer area.

Comment: You need to use #calendar .k-footer {} to set the background color. #calendar .k-footer a {} targets the text (which is rendered in a link element).